# Finitely generated uniformly amenable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Keller in "Amenable groups and varieties of groups" introduces uniformly amenable groups as groups such that 
there is a function $a: ]0,1[ \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that
for any finite subset $A \subset G$ and
for any $k \in ]0,1[$ 
there is a finite subset $U$ of $G$ such that

1. $|U|< a(k,|A|)$ and
2. $\forall a \in A$, $|U \cap aU| > k |U|$.

Wysoczánski "On uniformly amenable groups" gives an example of a amenable group which is not uniformly amenable 
(it's $G = \oplus G_p$ where $G_p$ are the upper-triangular 3x3 matrices wit 1 on the diagonal and entries in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$).

Bożejko in "Uniformly amenable discrete groups" proves that groups of polynomial growth are uniformly amenable.

An example of a finitely generated [elementarily amenable] group which is not uniformly amenable is given in Lemma 3.24 of [Ol'shanskii, Osin & Sapir](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701365)'s paper.
This is a consequence of a result that [non-virtually cyclic] uniformly amenable groups satisfy a law by Corollary 6.17 of [Druţu & Sapir](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405030)

Another example is mentioned by [de Cornulier and Mann](https://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/law_rf4.pdf) (the linked paper contains a few questions on group laws): it is mentionned that the Grigorchuk group does not satisfy a law. In particular it may not be uniformly amenable.

**Question:** Are there examples of finitely generated amenable but not uniformly amenable groups which satisfy a law?

Another question (but it would imply a positive answer to a question from de Cornulier and Mann, so I assume it is open) is: is there a group of intermediate growth which is uniformly amenable?

Comment: nilpotent $3\times 3$ matrices do not form a group

Comment: "non-uniformly amenable" means "not (uniformly amenable)" or "amenable but not uniformly amenable"?

Comment: sorry for the abusive language, I thought of the obvious nilpotent group in the 3x3 matrices and contracted it (into a nonsensical statement). Hopefully clarified both points...

Comment: But this group (the direct sum) seems to be uniformly amenable, since it is solvable, the author probably messed up something in his estimate. On the other hand such a direct sum but increasing both $p$ and the size of matrices, is non-uniformly-amenable.

Comment: The first f.g. elementary amenable groups satisfying no laws are due to BH Neumann in 1937 (subgroup of permutations of $\mathbf{Z}$ generated by infinite cycle $n\mapsto n+1$ and transposition $01$. That the ultrapower criterion implies that a group with no law is not uniformly amenable is immediate. So it should be attributed to Keller (1972).

Comment: @YCor Thanks for these informations (and correction of reference; should I edit?). I am right to extend BH Neumann's example into saying that for any infinite group $G$, $Sym_f(G) \rtimes G <Sym(G)$ has no law? (where $Sym_f(G)$ are the finitely supported permutations on the set $G$, $Sym(G)$ all permutations and $G$ is naturally identified with a subset of $Sym(G)$,since group multiplication of a given element is a permutation on $G$) The proof (probably) relies on the fact that the group of finitely supported permutations (of an infinite set) has no law.

Comment: Yes this is correct. In addition this group is finitely generated if $G$ is. One reason this group has no law is that it is dense in the group of all permutations of $G$, which contains a free subgroup.

Comment: Very nice way to see it. Do you have a reference for "solvable implies uniformly amenable"?

Comment: If $G$ satisfies some law $w$, then so do its ultrapowers. Hence if $G$ is solvable, so are its ultrapowers, which are therefore amenable. Hence $G$ is uniformly amenable.